# VS CODE Extensions Error: Download: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Tags: visual-studio-code

For no reason or factor that I know of suddenly vs code extensions stopped working for me. I reinstalled but I still get the following error message every time a few seconds after I try to install a certain extension:

```
[info] [perf] Render performance baseline is 35ms

[error] net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT: Download: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
        at $t.download (c:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:91:135892)
        at async ee.y (c:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:92:20021)
        at async ee.h (c:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:92:18112)
```

What could be the source of the problem and a way to solve it?

Thanks.

I currently have the latest version :**VS Code x64 v1.81.1**